# Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined in react: event object not being passed correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm currently trying to get a form to submit some text so that I can send it via axios to my backend api and am having trouble just simply getting the form to submit properly and access the data within react.

I have been following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/w-QJiQwlZzU (which I know is a little outdated, hence could be where the problem is coming from) and am using a component template from the antd library to create my form.

Currently this is my code for my form (Note the console logs were simply me trying to workout where the issue was)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";

class CustomForm extends React.Component {
  handleFormSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Been Submitted");
    console.log(event.target);
    const github_access_token = event.target.elements.github_access_token.value;

    console.log(github_access_token);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Form onFinish= {this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <Form.Item label="Access Token">
          <Input placeholder="Enter New Access Token..." name="github_access_token"/>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomForm;
```

The form is submitting as the console log is printing but I am trying to workout why the event.target is undefined as the event object exists, the event.preventDefault() is also causing an error which says event.preventDefault is not a function leading me to believe that the event object is not being passed correctly, but I'm not sure why

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: I haven't used this library before, but my interpretation of the [docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#API) would be that `onFinish` accepts the form values directly, not an event object.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the problem and it's working now, thank you for answering and so quickly as well. Legitimately been trying to work this out for over an hour now and it was something so simple. Thank You again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antd's [onFinish](https://ant.design/components/form/#API) function gives you form `values` object and not the form `event` and therefore you are getting the undefined error.

**Change your function like this**

```js
handleFormSubmit = (values) =>{
    console.log("Been Submitted");
    const github_access_token = values.github_access_token;
    console.log(github_access_token);
```

Comment: just saw the comments on this question and realised that it is solved... leaving this answer still ... no upvotes expected.. thanks.

Comment: Yep actually managed to fix it just before you posted thanks to Brian's comment, appreciate the swift and helpful answer